# Is there a common idiom equivalent to "tomato tomahto" in mandarin?

Tags: translation, phrase, idioms, equivalent-phrase, phrase-request

I'm being very nitpicky with a coworker (20s, first language is mandarin) and I'm trying to tease myself playfully by saying something along the lines of ["tomato tomahto"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tomato+tomahto) in mandarin.

I'm sure there is a translation for "it's all the same" (my stale interpretation for "tomato tomahto"), but I was hoping for a more playful phrase. Something more comparable to the joke-iness of "tomato tomahto", originated from this [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K75g7eRhH9M).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "半斤八两"? It's not funny though.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

- 哎呀，渣渣辉，张家辉有什么区别嘛？

Not sure if *everyone* will get it but it's quite funny.